# Вызов виртуального метода из метода родителя

Tags: c++, наследование

Есть два класса с виртуальной функцией, один наследует другой:

```
class Base {
    void            foo() {
        bar();
    }
    virtual void    bar() {
        cout << "base";
    }
};

class Derived {
    virtual void    bar() {
        cout << "derived";
    }
};

...

int main() {
    Derived* derived = new Derived();
    Base* bas = derived;
    bas->foo();
}
```

В итоге в этом случае вызывается Base::bar(), а хотелось бы чтобы вызывалось Derived::bar(), если у Base предопределен bar(), и Base::bar() если у Derived он не предопределен.

Comment: Где у Вас там `Base::bar()` вызывается? Если сделать Ваш код компилируемым(добавить в оба класса `public` и унаследовать `Derived` от `Base`) всё будет работать ровно так, как Вы описали в *желаемом*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас код неправильный, он не компилируется. Как минимум, Derived не знает, что он произведен от Base. А описали вы стандартное поведение виртуальных функций на C++.

Исправим ошибки:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base {
    void            foo() 
    {
        bar();
    }
    public:
    virtual void    bar() 
    {
        cout << "base";
    }
};

class Derived:public Base
{
    public:
    virtual void    bar() 
    {
        cout << "derived";
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Derived* derived = new Derived();
    Base* bas = derived;
    bas->Base::bar(); //вызвали базовый
    cout << endl;
    bas->bar();       //вызвали производный
}
```

- Если из `Derived` выкинуть метод `bar()`, в обоих случаях будет вызван метод базового класса.
- Дописка `Base::` перед вызовом метода позволяет даже у производного класса вызвать виртуальный метод базового класса.

[Пример на ideone](http://ideone.com/u7uq90)

Comment: Да, действительно, все работает как надо, проблема была в другом месте.